# Convert Flutter stream from Firebase to ints

Tags: firebase, flutter, reactive-programming

I have a Flutter app with chat functionality, where the chats are stored in Firebase database.  I have a `BottomNavigationBar` which has an icon button for Chats.  On this icon I display a badge if there are any unread chats:

```
               BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ImageIcon(AssetImage('images/icons.png')),
                      _unreadCount != null && _unreadCount > 0 ? Positioned(
                        right: 0,
                        child: new Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                          ),
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            minWidth: 12,
                            minHeight: 12,
                          ),
                          child: new Text(
                            '$_unreadCount',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 8,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ) : null
                    ].where((c) => c != null).toList(),
                  ),
                  title: Text('Chats', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
              ),
```

I fetch the `_unreadCount` using a method that returns a `Future<int>`.  It will query the chats firebase database and return the number of unread chats:

```
Future<int> getUnreadCount() async {

    bool isLoggedIn = await connection.isUserLoggedIn();
    int count = 0;

    if(isLoggedIn) {
      int userId = await _getUserId();

      final QuerySnapshot chatsQuerySnapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection("chats")
          .where("userIds", arrayContains: userId)
          .getDocuments();

      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = chatsQuerySnapshot.documents;

      if(documents != null && documents.isNotEmpty) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot chatsSnapshot in documents) {
          if(chatsSnapshot['unread'] as bool) {
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return count;
  }
```

However, because this is returning a `Future`, the badge will only get updated whenever the `BottomNavigationBar` is rebuilt (i.e. when I click on another tab) and the `Future` method gets called.

I need a method that returns a `Stream`, but I can't find any samples that work the way I want.  It seems to me that streams are only used when returning a collection/list of data, but I want just one `int`.  I don't know enough about reactive programming and I am new to it, but how do I query the Firebase in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact use case of the [`map`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html) function: simply wrap the relevant widget in your `BottomNavigationBar` in a `StreamBuilder` that takes a mapped version of your Firebase stream as an argument. See the following (untested) `Stream<int>` that you can use in the `StreamBuilder`:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("chats")
      .where("userIds", arrayContains: userId)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) {
        return snapshot.documents.fold(0, (count, doc) {
          return (doc['unread'] as bool) ? count + 1 : count;
        });
      });
```

The `fold` call could probably be cleaner with one of the many methods provided in Dart for `List`s/`Iterable`s but I will leave that up to you.

Here is a `Future<int>` you could make for the `FutureBuilder`, as discussed in the comments:

```
/// Returns the userId if the user is logged in, or null otherwise
Future<int> userIdWrapper() async {
    final isLoggedIn = await connection.isUserLoggedIn();
    return isLoggedIn ? await _getUserId() : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Looks promising, but as you can see I have a couple of calls that are `await`ing some future values (like `connection.isUserLoggedIn()` and `_getUserId()`.  How do I use them in a method that returns a Stream?

Comment: While you could keep that data in the same stream using some utilities provided by RxDart, it would probably be better to wrap the `StreamBuilder` with the stream I gave you into a `FutureBuilder` and then use the result provided in the build method of the `FutureBuilder` to build the `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: So, you could make an async function that returns a `Future<int>`  that returns null if the user is not logged in or an int of the userId if they are.

Comment: could you provide some sample code?  I didn't get how I would do this ..

Comment: Sure; I gave an example of the method you could create for the future as an edit to my answer. Do you know how to use FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder?

Comment: Yes I do know.  I think I get it now, I will try it later tonight and give you an update, thanks.